# how to insert a child gridview into a parent gridview 's each row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

how to insert a child gridview into a parent gridview. 
i want a asp.net code to insert any row dynamically into such type of grid,
i want the asp.net code to manage the already written data by user into columns of that type of grid regarding server trip while adding a new row into such type of grid for next entry for user's input.

Comment: Excellent! How much are you paying?

Comment: as i think this website is not a paid site??so your question is worthless..

Comment: Exactly, this is not a paid site, but the way you ask sounds like it is. If you expect people help you here you gotta provide a more useful question, with some code, and in a less demanding tone.

Comment: i don't know how u felt that my tone is demanding??i think i used "want" so many times into my asked question that's why u felt that,but exactly my meant was "i am actually needed.."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to:

- Specify a particular column ItemTemplate for the "main" GridView;
- Define the "child" GridView control inside it;
- Handle the "main" grid RowDataBound event and customize the necessary "child" grid properties;
- Handle the "child" RowInserting event event and perform necessary server-side operations.